Can we create a custom module for: Stock available qty range silder filter in layered navigation
I am seeking for module for magento 2.4.5 need to create : Stock available qty range silder filter in layered navigation like price range slider. which one use for price range slider as well.
Can anyone suggest steps to create the same.

Yes, you can create a custom module in Magento 2 to add a Stock Available Quantity Range Slider Filter in the layered navigation. This will allow customers to filter products based on their available stock quantity using a slider. Magento's layered navigation system allows for custom attributes to be added as filters, and you can extend it to include a stock quantity filter.

You have any refrence or steps that I can use?
